# How to replace all occurrences of regex as if applying replace repeatedly

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have text with a lot of product dimensions like "2x4" which I'd like to convert to "2 xby 4".

```
pattern = r"([0-9])\s*[xX\*]\s*([0-9])"

re.sub(pattern, r"\1 xby \2", "2x4")
'2 xby 4' # good

re.sub(pattern, r"\1 xby \2", "2x4x12")
'2 xby 4x12' # not good. need this to be '2 xby 4 xby 12'
```

One way of describing what I want to do is repeat the replacement until no more replacements can be made.  For example, I can simply to the above replacement twice to get what I want

```
x = re.sub(pattern, r"\1 xby \2", "2x4x12")
x = re.sub(pattern, r"\1 xby \2", x)
'2 xby 4 xby 12'
```

But I assume there's a better way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this lookahead regex for search:

```
r'([0-9]+)\s*[xX*]\s*(?=[0-9]+)'
```

`(?=[0-9]+)` is positive lookahead that just asserts the presence of second number by looking ahead but doesn't move the internal regex pointer by matching the number.

And use this for replacement:

```
r'\1 xby '
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY1zX0/2)

**Code:**

```
>>> pattern = r'([0-9]+)\s*[xX*]\s*(?=[0-9]+)'

>>> re.sub(pattern, r'\1 xby ', "2x4")
'2 xby 4'

>>> re.sub(pattern, r'\1 xby ', "2x4x12")
'2 xby 4 xby 12'
```

Comment: I think I like this better even though I thought I had the answer. Lookahead should get it since the replacements are done left to right.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you loosely explain what this is doing?  It seems right, but I don't fully understand why.

Comment: I've added an explanation of lookahead in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can approach this with a single pass, by thinking a little differently about it.  What you are really attempting to do is replace the x with xby -- so you can scan the whole string once, if you don't consume the right side of the digits.

For this, I recommend a look-ahead assertion. Basically, confirm that the thing you are replacing is followed by digits, but do not eat the digits in the process. This notation is (?=...) - see [re docpage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

For me, I have the following -- note that compiling the regex is optional and \d is usually preferred to [0-9]:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s*[xX\*]\s*(?=\d)")
pattern.sub(r"\1 xby ", "2x4x12")

'2 xby 4 xby 12'
```

In one pass, it will process the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to re-run the match against text that has already been transformed by the regex, there isn't really a better way.

It's sort of like unwinding a math problem, if you wanted to do: (2 + 3) + 4, you'd need to replace "(2 + 3)" to be able to replace "5 + 4" since the string "5" is nowhere in your original text.

What you may want to do is test your string for any match, and keep re-running your replacements on your previous results until no more matches are found.

Edit: You could also just make a few regexes for the number of times it might repeat and run them in descending order of length. I.e. look for 2x3x5x2 then 2x3x5 then 2x3, since progressively you won't hit anything that was already replaced.